# Is there an alternative to numpy.where() that doesn't return the list in ascending order?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

The `numpy.where()` function will always return a list in ascending order. I am using it to get indices from values in a list that are found in another list like this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5]
values = [4, 8]
indices = np.where(np.isin(lst, values))
```

The output is `[2,5]` instead of the expected `[5,2]`.

The problem, is that I need it to return the indices in the order that the values are found. So in my example, 4 is the first value, so the index that corresponds to it `(5)` should be first in the output, but it isn't. Is there an alternative to the `numpy.where()` function that keeps the order instead of sorting it? I could simply use some for loops and basic indexing to figure this out, but speed is super important because this is part of my custom 2d Max Pool function for a neural net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `values` is in sorted order, you can reorder the indices based on the output values:

```
lst = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5]
values = [4, 8]

a = np.array(lst)
m = np.isin(a, values)
order = np.argsort(a[m], kind='stable')

indices = np.where(np.isin(lst, values))[0][order]
```

Output: `[5, 2]`

Output with `lst = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 8]`: `array([5, 8, 2, 9])`

#### alternative

Another approach that would work with any order in `values` would be to broadcast the comparison:

```
#      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
lst = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 8]
values = [4, 8]

a, b = np.where(np.array(lst) == np.array(values)[:,None])

indices = b[np.argsort(a)]
# array([5, 8, 2, 9])

#### other example
#      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
lst = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 8]
values = [8, 4]

a, b = np.where(np.array(lst) == np.array(values)[:,None])

indices = b[np.argsort(a)]
# array([2, 9, 5, 8])
```

*NB. My previous statement was incorrect. I had misread `unique` instead of `where`.*

Comment: The result would always be `[2, 5]` wouldn't it? Other than that, this seems correct, but isn't it a statement of the problem that OP already knows they have?

Comment: @slothrop no, actually I said something wrong, I had a brain freeze and though `unique` was used not `where`. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: Try this with the original `lst` but with `values = [8, 4]`. It gives `[5 2]` instead of the expected `[2 5]`. The approach is OK if `values` is guaranteed to be in sorted order, but not if the order is arbitrary.

Comment: @slothrop I'm adding a generic approach that will work with any order of `values`

Comment: Although this works, its quite innefficient to do a broadcast `==`

Answer (score 1):

It's not `nonzero` (`where`) that's messing with the order.  It just returns the indices for its argument.

```
In [683]: np.isin(lst, values)
Out[683]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])

In [684]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[684]: (array([2, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

With a broadcasted comparison between the 2 lists, we can get a (2,8) boolean array:

```
In [685]: np.array(lst)==np.array(values)[:,None]
Out[685]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False]])

In [686]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[686]: (array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([5, 2], dtype=int64))
```

The 2nd array gives the indices in the order that they occur in `values`.

`isin` effectively does a logical `or` on the rows of this boolean array:

```
In [687]: (np.array(lst)==np.array(values)[:,None]).any(axis=0)
Out[687]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False])
```

`np.isin` actually uses `np.in1d` (with some reshape).  For your case they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
i1 = np.argsort(lst)
i1[np.searchsorted(lst, values, sorter=i1)]
array([5, 2], dtype=int64)
```